# sum67: why is it "timed out"?

Tags: python, timeout

For the "sum67" python exercise in codebat, all of my results are returning a "Timed out" result. Nonetheless, when I run the code in IDLE it seems to work perfectly.

In the exercise, I must return the sum of all the `nums` in the list. But the `nums` between a 6 and a 7, included, must not count.

Can someone help me find the reason for this? I'm dying

```
def sum67(nums):
    count = 0
    while 6 in nums: 
        place_6 = nums.index(6)
        place_7 = nums.index(7)+1
        del nums[place_6:place_7]
    for i in nums:
        count += i
    return count
```

Thanks so much :D

Comment: What is your input? and if the purpose of the exercise is to delete the element from the list, you can simply state `del nums[place_6]`

Comment: Also your for loop `for i in nums` basically equals to `len(nums)`

Comment: Instead of that second loop, you could also try `count = sum(nums)`

Comment: Take a look at my answer @pedroswainer and let me know if something is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code fails is because you assume that **for every `6` there is going to be a `7` after it as well** and that might not be the case.

When that happens, your code either:

- raises a `ValueError` when **no** `7` exists (try with `[1, 6, 2]`), or
- times-out if the `7` does exist but **before** the `6` (slicing fails to remove anything from the `list` but you try over and over again anyway..)(try with `[1, 7, 6, 2]`)

How about this instead:

```
def sum67(nums):
    stop = False
    count = 0
    for number in nums:
        if number == 6:
            stop = True
        elif stop and number == 7:
            stop = False
        else:
            if not stop:
                count += number
    return count
```

You simply keep adding the terms unless you meet a `6`. If you do, you stop adding until a `7` is found.

Note that this can definitely be improved. it is a *quick and dirty* type of solution which [passes the tests](http://codingbat.com/prob/p108886) nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to get a `timeout error` because `while <int> in <array>` will keep returning true until you edit the  being tested in the while loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works fine, so I'm thinking that CodingBat has an extremely unforgiving timeout threshold!  It's them, not you.

Comment: it's not them @Zev. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum67(nums):
    sum = 0
    test=True
    for i in nums:
        if i == 6:
            test=False
            continue
        if  test == False and i == 7:
            test=True
            continue
        if test==True:
            sum+=i
    return sum
```

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your contribution. Please edit your post to explain what your code is expected to do and why it is answering the question. Also check the alignment, it seems to be off.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, use this code instead:

```
def sum67(nums):
  while 6 in nums: 
    del nums[nums.index(6):nums.index(7,nums.index(6))+1]
  return sum(nums)
```